# Why the type position of a method is marked as negative?

Tags: scala, contravariance, type-systems

Sorry I have asked some questions like this one, but I still can't get a clear answer, maybe my bad English and unclear expression puzzled the kind people.

When I read the "Type Parameterization" in this article: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html, I see there are some explanation about the type positions:

> As a somewhat contrived example, consider the following class definition, where the variance of several positions is annotated with ^+ (for positive) or ^- (for negative):
>
> ```
>    abstract class Cat[-T, +U] {
>      def meow[W^-](volume: T^-, listener: Cat[U^+, T^-]^-)
>      : Cat[Cat[U^+, T^-]^-, U^+]^+
>    }
> ```

I can understand most of this class, except the `W` position. I don't understand why it marked as **negative**, and there is no explanation in the whole document.

It also says:

> Type parameters annotated with + may only be used in positive positions, while type parameters annotated with - may only be used in negative positions.

How can I find a type with `-` annotation in position `W` to fit this negative position?

Comment: It is a *contrived* example. This means it is not obliged to make any practical sense. It just illustrates a language feature (badly).

Comment: The example is contrived, but the positions are not. You can just focus on the meow[W^-] with the same question, and ignore the other crazy parts.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, the example is actually erroneous. W does not denote a type here and thus has no variance position.

Comment: @n.m. The article claims it has a position along with the method value parameters:  `The positions of the type parameter, W, and the two value parameters, volume and listener, are all negative`

Comment: I have read this claim. It makes no sense. Position of W is not something that can have variance, because T and U, the parameters of the class, cannot appear in that position.

Comment: Scratch that, it makes sense and I understand what it means now. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language reference says:

- The variance position of a method parameter is the opposite of the variance position of the enclosing parameter clause.
- The variance position of a type parameter is the opposite of the variance position of the enclosing type parameter clause.
- The variance position of the lower bound of a type declaration or type parameter is the opposite of the variance position of the type declaration or parameter.

OK what does it mean for a type parameter to have a variance position?

```
class Moo[+A, -B] {
  def foo[X] (bar : Y) ...
```

So Y is in a contravariant position, this is clear. We can put B in its position, but not A.

But what does it mean for X to be in a contravariant position? We cannot substitute A or B or anything there, it's just a formal parameter!

That's true, but this thing *can have subordinate positions* which are types, and have variance. So we need to count the position of X when tracking how many times we flip variance. There's no subordinate clauses of X here, but consider this:

```
class Moo[+A, -B] {
  def foo[X >: Z] (bar : B) ...
```

We probably can replace Z with either A or B, but which is correct? Well, the position of Z is the opposite of that of X, and the position of X is the opposite of that of the top-level, which is covariant, so Z must be covariant too. Let's check:

```
abstract class Moo[+A, -B] {
      def foo[X >: A] (bar : B)
}    
defined class Moo
```

Looks like we are right!

Comment: What does the top-level mean ? Is it covariant by default ?

Comment: @HaoRen Top-level means not enclosed in any other level. It is always covariant (not just by default), the language reference explicitly says that.

Comment: @n.m. what is **the enclosing parameter clause** and **the enclosing type parameter clause**? can you give an example?

Comment: @Guo [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427270/how-to-understand-the-variance-position-of-a-method-parameter-is-the-opposite-o) explains it.

Comment: @n.m. `class Foo[-A, +B] {
  def foo(a : A) = {
    def bar(b : B) = ???
  }
}`, in this case, `foo` function's *"the enclosing parameter clause"* is `class Foo`, and `bar` function's *"the enclosing parameter clause"* is `foo` function, is it right?

Comment: @guo no sorry the link is in fact incorrect. Here's a correct example with several levels: `class Foo[-A, +B] { def foo(a : A, b: B => A, c: (A => B) => A) = 123 }`. Here `a` is a parameter, `b` is a parameter which itself is a function and so has a parameter (which has an enclosing parameter clause, `b`), and `c` is a parameter which has a parameter which has a parameter. You can see how variance is flipped with each level: `a` is contravariant , the parameter of `b` is covariant, and the parameter of the parameter of `c` is contravariant again.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you very much! I got it!

Answer (score 1):

There is a familiar example in the spec:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variance-annotations

`Sequence.append` is example 4.5.2 in the pdf, but the markdown isn't numbered at the moment.

```
abstract class Sequence[+A] {
  def append[B >: A](x: Sequence[B]): Sequence[B]
}
```

In real life, see [the doc for `Seq.++`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/#scala.collection.Seq), ignoring the "use case" and clicking on the "full signature" to show the lower bound.

This is the same pattern as in other widening operations like [`Option.getOrElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/#scala.Option), where you're getting back a possibly wider type than you started with.

Here's an example of how it makes sense in terms of substitution:

Given a `Seq[Fruit]`, I can append a `Seq[Orange]`. Since `Apple <: Fruit`, I can also append the oranges to a `Seq[Apple]` and get fruits back.

That's why the `B` type parameter wants to be bound by a covariant parameter. The variance position of `B` is classified as negative, for purposes of variance checking, but `B` itself is not annotated.

Funny thing is that this parses:

```
scala> trait X { def append[-](): Unit }
defined trait X
```