# Why `trait X { def append[-](): Unit }` compiles?

Tags: scala, type-systems

From the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374938/342235, there is some code which looks strange:

```
trait X { 
  def append[-](): Unit 
}
```

Why it can be compiled? I mean the `[-]` is strange

Comment: Did you check out the covariance notations and how they can be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is strange, but in this context `-` is a acceptable identifier for a type parameter. Here is a longer example:

```
class Y {
  def identity[-](x: -): - = x
}
(new Y).identity(5) // returns 5
```

The `-` inside `[-]` here is a normal type name, just like the `-` as the class name in the following code:

```
class -
```

Note that because the type parameters of methods cannot be marked contravariant the compiler will not interpret the `-` as indicating contravariance. On the other hand this will not parse:

```
class Z[-] {}
```

Comment: So `-` here is just a normal type name, just like `class -`, right?

Comment: Yes, inside of identity it is no different than any other type.