# How to understand "The variance position of a method parameter is the opposite of the variance position of the enclosing parameter clause."

Tags: scala, type-systems

I see this sentence is [scala specification (pdf)](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The variance position of a method parameter is the opposite of the variance position of the enclosing parameter clause.

Which is on page 44.

But I can't quite understand it. Could you give me some samples?

Comment: You should add a link to the relevant specification, and what page this quote occurs on. Context is often very important here!

Answer (score 7):

So, let's start with a motivating example. Suppose I write the following:

```
class Foo[+A] {
  def foo(a : A) = ???
}
```

Now, by annotating the type parameter `A` with a `+`, I've declared that `Foo` is covariant in `A`, which is to say that if `X <: Y`, then `Foo[X] <: Foo[Y]`. So, suppose I have such a `Foo[X]` and I try to pass it to a function which requires a `Foo[Y]`:

```
def bar(a : Y, x : Foo[Y]) = {
  x.foo(a)
}
```

Now, `bar` tries to call `x.foo` with a `Y`. But `x` is a `Foo[X]`, and `X` is a subtype of `Y` - so it's like trying to pass an `Object` to a function requiring a `String` - there's no guarantee that the `Object` contains everything that's needed to do this. So the definition of `Foo` above is invalid - to use the terminology in the specification, the type parameter `A` is covariant, but you've attempted to use it in a *contravariant position* - as the parameter to a function.

The set of rules set out in the Scala spec where you've referenced are the rules used by the Scala compiler to determine the *variance position* of different places in the code, which it uses to check that you haven't done anything like the definition of `Foo` above. The specific clause you identify gives the rule corresponding to the example above - it says that the variance position of a parameter clause (e.g. within the parameter list of a function) is the opposite of the surrounding variance position.

Usually, this means that parameter clauses are contravariant. However, things can get multiply inverted:

```
class Foo[A, B] {
  def foo(a : A) = {
    def bar(b : B) = ???
  }
}
```

Here, the parameter clause of `foo` is contravariant, and hence the parameter clause of `bar` is inverted again, and is covariant. So the following definition is valid:

```
class Foo[-A, +B] {
  def foo(a : A) = {
    def bar(b : B) = ???
  }
}
```